# What is the difference between .text, .value, and .value2?

Tags: excel, vba

What is the difference between `.text`, `.value`, and `.value2`? Such as when should target.text, target.value, and target.value2 be used?

Comment: LCase(Target.Value) will fail if Target.Value is not coercable to a string since LCase requires a string to an argument. You should check the VarType first as per my answer. Also note you could use UCase instead and compare directly to "HLO": not much point in operating on a literal.

Comment: Thanks for the information about VarType. As far as the LCase or UCase for this, it really wouldn't matter which one I used. Some people type it in as hlo and others type it in as HLO. From what I saw it appeared the lower case one was used more often.

Answer (score 306, accepted):

`.Text` gives you a string representing what is displayed on the screen for the cell. Using `.Text` is usually a bad idea because you could get `####`

`.Value2` gives you the underlying value of the cell (could be empty, string, error, number (double) or boolean)

`.Value` gives you the same as `.Value2` except if the cell was formatted as currency or date it gives you a VBA currency (which may truncate decimal places) or VBA date.

Using `.Value` or `.Text` is usually a bad idea because you may not get the real value from the cell, and they are slower than `.Value2`

For a more extensive discussion see my [Text vs Value vs Value2](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/)

Comment: I have the following value in a cell: `1420470000000000`. I want to get it as a string. Using `.Value` and `Value2` both return the following for me: `1.42047E+15`. What I actually want is the full value as a string i.e. `1420470000000000`. I'm using `.Formula` for the time being but would be keen to know of a more appropriate solution?

Comment: I would probably use Format to control how the number gets converted to a string: var = Format(Range("a1").Value2, "#")

Comment: I hope this is not a separate question but: What is the default? The OP claims vaguely that leaving out text/value/value2 is problematic, but surely it defaults to *one* of them?

Comment: The default is .Value

Comment: interesting difference about `.Text` is that it returns either `String` if the `Range` contains the same texts (even if different values), or `Null` otherwise

Comment: @Mat's Mug - the problem is that Excel does not have a true Date data-type - excel dates and times are just doubles that depend on whatever format has been applied or changed by the user to appear as dates, times or currency or just a number. So Value is coercing an Excel double to a VBA date but Value2 is not doing any coercing ... For dates coercing the double to a date is probably not doing any damage as long as the code understands that its dependent on a changeable format: pros and cons either way - what we really need is more native Excel data types to avoid this problem.

Comment: Another oddity I came across is in VBA setting one range equal to another. The range in question had numbers stored as text (with the little green triangle indicating this). Setting a range equal to these numbers stored as text using .Values/.Values2 causes the values to be converted to numbers (which I didn't want). The only way I found around this was using .Formula, just to throw another spanner in the works.

Comment: When I want to set a cell value equal to another cell without a type conversion (for example, without converting a number stored as text to a number) I use this: 
 `Format$(Range.Value2, Range.NumberFormat)`.

Comment: I think it's also worth noting that `Range.Text` is a *read-only* property, considering OP's note "`Sometimes if I use .text it gives me an error and I need to use .value when I am ... manipulating the text within a cell`"

Comment: @blobbles I default to setting a cell's value using `.Formula` (even if just inputting a value) and reading its contents using `.Value2` (even if contents is not a value).

Comment: Just another oddity just discovered. With texts longer than 255 characters, `Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(xlsCell.Value)` works, while `Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(xlsCell)` does not work, indicating that .value is not the exact default.

Answer (score 62):

In addition to the [answer from Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17359934/1026) and the MSDN information for:

[.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff195193%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
[.Value2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff193553%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
[.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff840217%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

you could analyze the following tables for better understanding of differences between these three properties.

[image]

Comment: @Chris, use `.Value` as standard property all the time- for text and numbers. Use `.Value2` when you think of date and some numbers. And use `.Text` always if you need to keep formatting of anything you have in cell/range. So, your question example if correct!

Comment: why the date changed from 10:12 to 10:05? typo?

Comment: I think it is just time elapsed between generating results and time of making screen shot

Answer (score 26):

`target.Value` will give you a `Variant` type

`target.Value2` will give you a `Variant` type as well but a `Date` is coerced to a `Double`

`target.Text` attempts to coerce to a `String` and will fail if the underlying `Variant` is not coercable to a `String` type

The safest thing to do is something like

```
Dim v As Variant
v = target.Value 'but if you don't want to handle date types use Value2
```

And check the type of the variant using `VBA.VarType(v)` before you attempt an explicit coercion.

Answer (score 11):

Regarding conventions in C#. Let's say you're reading a cell that contains a date, e.g. 2014-10-22.

When using:

`.Text`, you'll get the formatted representation of the date, as seen in the workbook on-screen:
**2014-10-22**. This property's type is always `string` but may not always return a satisfactory result.

`.Value`, the compiler attempts to convert the date into a `DateTime` object: **{2014-10-22 00:00:00}** Most probably only useful when reading dates.

`.Value2`, gives you the real, underlying value of the cell. In the case for dates, it's a date serial: **41934**. This property can have a different type depending on the contents of the cell. For date serials though, the type is `double`.

So you can retrieve and store the value of a cell in either `dynamic`, `var` or `object` but note that the value will always have some sort of innate type that you will have to act upon.

```
dynamic x = ws.get_Range("A1").Value2;
object  y = ws.get_Range("A1").Value2;
var     z = ws.get_Range("A1").Value2;
double  d = ws.get_Range("A1").Value2;      // Value of a serial is always a double
```

Answer (score 4):

.Text is the formatted cell's displayed value; .Value is the value of the cell possibly augmented with date or currency indicators; .Value2 is the raw underlying value stripped of any extraneous information.

```
range("A1") = Date
range("A1").numberformat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
debug.print range("A1").text
debug.print range("A1").value
debug.print range("A1").value2

'results from Immediate window
2018-06-14
6/14/2018 
43265 

range("A1") = "abc"
range("A1").numberformat = "_(_(_(@"
debug.print range("A1").text
debug.print range("A1").value
debug.print range("A1").value2

'results from Immediate window
   abc
abc
abc

range("A1") = 12
range("A1").numberformat = "0 \m\m"
debug.print range("A1").text
debug.print range("A1").value
debug.print range("A1").value2

'results from Immediate window
12 mm
12
12
```

If you are processing the cell's value then reading the raw .Value2 is marginally faster than .Value or .Text. If you are locating errors then .Text will return something like `#N/A` as text and can be compared to a string while .Value and .Value2 will choke comparing their returned value to a string. If you have some custom cell formatting applied to your data then .Text may be the better choice when building a report.

Answer (score 2):

`Value2` is *almost always* the best choice to read from or write to an Excel cell or a range... from VBA.

```
Range.Value2 '<------Best way
```

Each of the following can be used to ***read*** from a range:

```
v = [a1]
v = [a1].Value
v = [a1].Value2
v = [a1].Text 
v = [a1].Formula
v = [a1].FormulaR1C1
```

Each of the following can be used to ***write*** to a range:

```
[a1] = v
[a1].Value = v
[a1].Value2 = v
[a1].Formula = v
[a1].FormulaR1C1 = v
```

To read many values from a large range, or to write many values, it can be orders of magnitude faster to do the entire operation in one go instead of cell by cell:

```
arr = [a1:z999].Value2
```

If `arr` is a variable of type Variant, the above line actually creates an [OLE SAFEARRAY structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-safearray) of variants 26 columns wide and 999 rows tall and points the Variant `arr` at the SAFEARRAY structure in memory.

```
[a1].Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2).Value2 = arr
```

The above line writes the entire array to the worksheet in one go no matter how big the array is (as long as it will fit in the worksheet).

The default property of the range object is the `Value` property. So if no property is specified for the range, the `Value` property is silently referenced by default.

However, `Value2` is the quickest property to access range values and when reading it returns the true underlying cell value. It ignores Number Formats, Dates, Times, and Currency and returns numbers as the VBA Double data type, always. Since `Value2` attempts to do less work, it executes slightly more quickly than does `Value`.

The `Value` property, on the other hand, checks if a cell value  has a Number Format of Date or Time and will return a value of the VBA Date data type in these cases. If your VBA code will be working with the Date data type, it may make sense to retrieve them with the `Value` property. And writing a VBA Date data type to a cell will automatically format the cell with the corresponding date or time number format. And
writing a VBA Currency data type to a cell will automatically apply the currency Number Format to the appropriate cells.

Similarly, `Value` checks for cell currency formatting and then
returns values of the VBA Currency data type. This can lead to
loss of precision as the VBA Currency data type only recognizes
four decimal places (because the VBA Currency data type is really just a 64-bit Integer scaled by 10000) and so values are rounded to four places,
at most. And strangely, that precision is cut to just two decimal
places when using `Value` to write a VBA Currency variable to a worksheet range.

The read-only `Text` property always returns a VBA String data type. The value returned by `Range.Text` is a textual representation of what is displayed in each cell, inclusive of Number Formats, Dates, Times, Currency, and Error text. This is not an efficient way to get numerical values into VBA as implicit or explicit coercion is required. `Text` will return ####### when columns are too thin and it will slow down even more when some row heights are adjusted. `Text` is always VERY slow compared to `Value` and `Value2`. However, since `Text` retains the formatted appearance of cell values, `Text` may be useful, especially for populating userform controls with properly formatted text values.

Similarly, both `Formula` and `FormulaR1C1` always return values as a VBA String data type. If the cell contains a formula then `Formula` returns its A1-style representation and `FormulaR1C1` returns its R1C1 representation. If a cell has a hard value instead of a formula then both `Formula` and `FormulaR1C1` ignore all formatting and return the true underlying cell value exactly like `Value2` does... and then take a further step to convert that value to a string. Again, this is not an efficient way to get numerical values into VBA as implicit or explicit coercion is required. However, `Formula` and `FormulaR1C1` *must* be used to read cell
formulas. And they *should* be used to write formulas to cells.

If cell A1 contains the numeric value of 100.25 with a currency number formatting
of $#,##0.00_);($#,##0.00) consider the following:

```
MsgBox [a1].Value                   'Displays:  100.25
MsgBox TypeName([a1].Value)         'Displays: Currency
 
MsgBox [a1].Value2                  'Displays:  100.25
MsgBox TypeName([a1].Value2)        'Displays: Double
 
MsgBox [a1].Text                    'Displays: $ 100.25
MsgBox TypeName([a1].Text)          'Displays: String
 
MsgBox [a1].Formula                 'Displays: 100.25
MsgBox TypeName([a1].Formula)       'Displays: String
 
MsgBox [a1].FormulaR1C1             'Displays: 100.25
MsgBox TypeName([a1].FormulaR1C1)   'Displays: String
```

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, I wanted to see how `Value` performed against `Value2`. After about 12 trials of similar processes, I could not see any significant differences in speed so I would always recommend using `Value`. I used the below code to run some tests with various ranges.

If anyone sees anything contrary regarding performance, please post.

```
Sub Trial_RUN()
    For t = 0 To 5
        TestValueMethod (True)
        TestValueMethod (False)
    Next t

End Sub




Sub TestValueMethod(useValue2 As Boolean)
Dim beginTime As Date, aCell As Range, rngAddress As String, ResultsColumn As Long
ResultsColumn = 5

'have some values in your RngAddress. in my case i put =Rand() in the cells, and then set to values
rngAddress = "A2:A399999" 'I changed this around on my sets.



With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
.Range(rngAddress).Offset(0, 1).ClearContents


beginTime = Now

For Each aCell In .Range(rngAddress).Cells
    If useValue2 Then
        aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = aCell.Value2 + aCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value2
    Else
        aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = aCell.Value + aCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value
    End If

Next aCell

Dim Answer As String
 If useValue2 Then Answer = " using Value2"

.Cells(Rows.Count, ResultsColumn).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = DateDiff("S", beginTime, Now) & _
            " seconds. For " & .Range(rngAddress).Cells.Count & " cells, at " & Now & Answer


End With


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Your timing is totally swamped by the overhead of making references to cells (cell-by-cell walking is a disaster for performance). Try using a large range of cells being assigned to a variant and creating a 2-D variant arry.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams yea, you're right. I call this *CRINGE CODE* meaning it's code I wrote before I knew about something else (i.e. the importance of arrays), and looking back on it I... you guessed it.... cringe. Anyway, thanks for tip. I may repost something later.

Comment: And the difference will reveal itself better when Dates and Times are included in the source data. `.Value2` is faster.