# Convert to text using VB-macro (including line breaks within cells)

Tags: excel, line-breaks, vba

I would like to convert an Excel sheet into several text files. The sheet contains two columns:

- Column A gives the names for the generated text files
- Column B provides content - contains line breaks within cells

The conversion works using the following code, but line breaks are not imported to the text file - all text is in one line:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim oTxt As Object

    For Each cell In Ark1.Range("A1:A" & Ark1.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        ' you can change the sheet1 to your own choice    
        saveText = cell.Text
        Open "H:\Webshop_Zpider\S-solutions" & saveText & ".txt" For Output As #1
        Print #1, cell.Offset(0, 1).Text
        Close #1
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Can anybody help me with that?

Hi, the result of using Siddharths suggestions: line breaks are included! But all generated files are not named and saved as I wanted. All files get the name S-solutions plus content of colum A (e.g. S-solutionsS-4001-K-T.txt) and are saved in folder H:\Webshop_Zpider. However, what I want is: Filename: content of colum A (e.g.S-4001-K-T.txt) and folder H:\Webshop_Zpider\S-solutions. How can I change that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Replace this

```
Print #1, cell.Offset(0, 1).Text
```

with

```
Print #1, Replace(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, vbLf, vbCrLf)
```

Also one Tip! Do not use `.Text`. Use `.Value`

Comment: Explaining the tip: See [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2)

Comment: One more thing: All files get the name S-solutions plus content of colum A and are saved in folder H:\Webshop_Zpider. However, what I want is: Filename: content of colum A and folder H:\Webshop_Zpider\S-solutions. How can I change that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please update your question with the result that you are getting and the result expected

Comment: Hi, the result of using Siddharths suggestions: line breaks are included, but files are not not named and saved as I wanted. All files get the name S-solutions plus content of colum A (e.g. S-solutionsS-4001-K-T.txt) and are saved in folder H:\Webshop_Zpider. However, what I want is: Filename: content of colum A (e.g.S-4001-K-T.txt) and folder H:\Webshop_Zpider\S-solutions. How can I change that?

Comment: Try this `Open "H:\Webshop_Zpider\S-solutions\" & saveText & ".txt" For Output As #1` notice the "\" after "S-solutions"

Comment: Thanks, Siddharth! Works again :-)

Answer (score 0):

First you should Open the Textfile only ONCE and not for every Cell
Then you can do

```
Print #1, cell.Offset(0, 1).Text & vbnewline
```

For the celltext and a new line.