# When should I use value() on cells() in vba?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to read and set Excel cells values with `Cells(1,1)`. I was successful with reading this value. But I've seen code with `Cells(1,1).Value()`. So when should I use the notation itself: `Cells(1,1)` and notation with `.Value()` `(Text()/Value2())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default property of `Cells` in VBA is `Value`. There's no difference in using it vs not using it.

I prefer to explicitly define the `Value` property though for the sake of debugging and helping others who may read my code in future as it is a clear indication of what the code is trying to achieve.

Comment: This holds especially true if you're also handling `Range` variables in your code, as you won't be confused if you, for example, are also copying Ranges. For more infos on .Text/.Value/.Value2 see [this SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17363466/4600127).