# Avoiding the clipboard when copying large ranges to another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm interested in copying a large range from one workbook to another. Currently, I am using the copy and paste functions. The macro worked on smaller files, but now I have a very large file and I am running into an error at `ActiveSheet.Paste`. I think it is because what I am copying is too large for the clipboard. Does that sound right? If so, I would like to avoid the clipboard all together. Here is my code currently.

```
DeptReceivedWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy


APPS_AuditWB.Activate
APPS_AuditWB.Sheets(3).Select
ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: If you don't need formatting, just set one range to another. Avoid copy/paste all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of these:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub valuesCopy()
    With DeptReceivedWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Copy
    End With

    APPS_AuditWB.Sheets(3).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub

Public Sub directCopy1()
    Dim cr As Range, fr As Long, lr As Long, fc As Long, lc As Long

    Set cr = DeptReceivedWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    fr = cr.Row:    lr = fr + cr.Rows.Count - 2
    fc = cr.Column: lc = fc + cr.Columns.Count - 1
    Set cr = cr.Offset(1).Resize(lr, lc)

    With APPS_AuditWB.Sheets(3)
        .Range(.Cells(fr, fc), .Cells(lr, lc)).Value2 = cr.Value2
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub directCopy2()
    Dim cr As Range, fr As Long, lr As Long, fc As Long, lc As Long

    Set cr = DeptReceivedWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    fr = cr.Row:    lr = cr.Rows.Count - 1
    fc = cr.Column: lc = cr.Columns.Count
    Set cr = cr.Offset(1).Resize(lr, lc)

    With APPS_AuditWB.Sheets(3)
        .Cells(fr, fc).Resize(lr, lc).Value2 = cr.Value2
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Typo - `lc` isn't assigned a value.  But this only works if the copied range begins in A1 - maybe better to use `.Cells(fr, fc).Resize(lr, lc).Value2= ur.Value2`  ?

Comment: Thank you @paul bica, I used directCopy1 and it worked like a charm! This is my first time seeing Value2. I take it that Value2 is for the value of a range, where plain old value is just for a single cell?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Value2 is similar to "raw data" where no formatting is involved. The [difference between .Value and .Value2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2) is related to formatting of the Currency and Date data types. .Value2 is the faster and more reliable method because it returns the date as a number (serial), for example if A1 contains **NOW()**: .Text: **#######**, .Value: **9/28/2015 6:43:43 PM**, .Value2: **42275.7803555556**, .Formula: **=NOW()**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you only copy the range you want rather than copying a (presumably) header row and then deleting it from the target:

```
Dim rgCopy as range
set rgCopy = DeptReceivedWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
set rgCopy = rgCopy.Resize(rgCopy.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
rgCopy.Copy Destination:=APPS_AuditWB.Sheets(3).Cells(i + 1, 1)
```