# How can i detect null value in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with value detection in excel. When it doesn't have value in cell i want excel show me message warning rather than zero value and i have code below.

```
Public Function MySum(a As Range, b As Range) As String

    If IsNull(a) And IsNull(b) Then
        MySum = "No value sir"
    Else
        MySum = a.Value + b.Value
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways to validate parameters

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MySum(a As Range, b As Range) As String
    Dim itmsOK As Boolean

    MySum = "No value"  'default return value, if a or b are not valid

    itmsOK = (Not a Is Nothing And Not b Is Nothing)    'validate the Range objects

    If itmsOK Then itmsOK = (Not IsNull(a.Value2) And Not IsNull(b.Value2))       'DB vals
    If itmsOK Then itmsOK = (Len(Trim(a.Value2)) > 0 And Len(Trim(b.Value2)) > 0) 'Empty
    If itmsOK Then itmsOK = (IsNumeric(a.Value2) And IsNumeric(b.Value2))         'Numbers

    If itmsOK Then MySum = Val(a.Value2) + Val(b.Value2)   'if both valid, perform math

End Function
```

(checking just for Nulls is more specific to importing data from a database)

Comment: Thank you. But what does value2 use for?

Comment: When working with cells (ranges) there are 3 properties used to get the actual data from the Range object: `rng.Value`, `rng.Value2`, and `rng.Text`. `rng.Value2` is the "raw data", extracted without formatting, for example if A1 contains NOW(): .Text: **#######** (when column is too narrow to show entire value), .Value: **9/28/2015 6:43:43 PM**, .Value2: **42275.7803555556**. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2) has more info about the differences between them

Answer (score 0):

CountA function returns value "0" when when the cell is empty. SO you can use CountA function in this case to check whether there is any data in the cell.

```
If CountA("a") = 0 and CountA("b") = 0 Then
MySum = "No value sir"
    Else
MySum = a.Value + b.Value
Else IF
END
```

Comment: You might want to expand your answer to explain what the added functions do.