# Precision of Excel Spreadsheet Calculation different from Excel VBA Calculation

Tags: excel, variables, operators, numerical-methods, vba

I am working on a spreadsheet that is performing calculations on very small numbers, on the order of 1E-14. I had a draft of my process that leverages the spreadsheet and does not store any data in VBA variables. I do not like that approach and wanted to take the entire process behind the scenes into VBA.

What I am noticing is I cannot get the two approaches to match. Same operations different results. I am working with Excel 2013

```
An example in a cell 
=B42*COS(2*PI()*E$41*A42) 

or if I plug in values taking all figures reported i get the following 
0.156434465*Cos(2*3.14159265358979*0.012*0.05) 

this results in 
1.56433353400222E-01
```

If I do the same thing in VBA

```
gsum = Round(data(i + 1, 1), 10) * Cos(2 * pi * Freq * i * dt)

or 
0.156434465*Cos(2*3.14159265358979*0.012*1*0.05) 
i get a different answer 
Watch:Round(data(i + 1, 1), 10) * Cos(2 * Pi * Freq * i * dt):    
0.156433353359992 : Variant/Double : Calculation.realFT
```

I am not sure how to combat this. Somehow I lose a little each time. Everything on the VBA side is declared of type double except for I.

Any ideas on how i can get VBA to match the spreadsheets precision?

I know the differences are small but I am doing a lot of operations and they add up. Also I am confined to Excel for the application.

***UPDATE***

So I was looking at this some more and i have narrowed that the problem to the muliplication step between the Cosine output and the cell value. In both the excel and Excel VBA versions I can see that they are both the same but I am stuck with the following

```
In Excel 
0.999992893893247000000*0.156434465= 1.56433353400222E-01

In Excel VBA 
0.999992893893247000000*0.156434465= 1.56433353359991861557855E-01
```

who is right?

Comment: It is possible that Excel's cosine is better than VBA's. VBA is old (no change since the late 1990s) but Excel itself has been constantly  updated. Maybe also a 32 vs 64 bit issue.

Comment: @JohnColeman Hmmm, It seems VBA won't let me use the worksheet function ala WorksheetFunction.Cos. Anyway around this?

Comment: I *think* that `Application.Evaluate("0.156434465*Cos(2*3.14159265358979*0.012*1*0.05)")` will use Excel's cos() (rather than VBA's). But -- in my case (Excel 2010) I can't detect any difference between the VBA and the Excel evaluation of the expression -- they both return 0.156433353359992. Charles Williams is a guru when it comes to high-precision Excel VBA. You might enjoy his blog: https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/ . This is also cool: https://newtonexcelbach.wordpress.com/

Comment: Application.Evaluate gives me the VBA answer, maybe the same pathway? If you put the two values in two cells and multiply them then I get the other value. Is that the same for 2010

Comment: Python can multiply long integers while retaining precision. I did this multiplication `999992893893247*156434465` in Python with the result `156433353359991861557855`, suggesting that VBA is correct. By the way VBA is giving 24 decimals of precision indicating 55 binary bits!

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions

Change variable type from double to currency or decimal (variant), or string

Double: 8 bytes

```
-1.79769313486232e+308 to -4.94065645841247E-324 for negative values
 4.94065645841247E-324 to  1.79769313486232e+308 for positive values
```

<s>Currency: 8 bytes</s>

<s>`-922,337,203,685,477.5808 to 922,337,203,685,477.5807`</s>

Decimal: 12 bytes (declared as Variant, then use conversion function CDec)

```
+/- 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 if no decimal is use
+/-  7.9228162514264337593543950335 (28 decimal places)
```

---

Be aware of how to extract data from ranges to VBA:

```
Public Sub showData()
    Const NL As String = vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbTab
    Const FR As String = "0.156434465 * Cos(2 * 3.14159265358979 * 0.012 * 0.05)"

    Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant, v3 As Variant, v4 As Variant, v5 As Variant

    v1 = CDec((1 / 3) + (1 / 3) + (1.00059999999977E-03))
    v2 = CDec(CDec(1 / 3) + CDec(1 / 3) + CDec(1.00059999999977E-03))
    v3 = 0.156434465 * Cos(2 * 3.14159265358979 * 0.012 * 0.05)
    v4 = CDec(0.156434465 * Cos(2 * 3.14159265358979 * 0.012 * 0.05))
    v5 = CDec(CDec(0.156434465) * CDec(Cos(CDec(2 * 3.14159265358979 * 0.012 * 0.05))))

    With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
        MsgBox "Formula: " & vbTab & .Formula & NL & _
                "Text:   " & vbTab & .Text & NL & _
                "Value:  " & vbTab & .Value & NL & _
                "Value2: " & vbTab & .Value2 & vbCrLf & NL & _
                "VBA 1:  " & vbTab & v1 & NL & _
                "VBA 2:  " & vbTab & v2 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "Formula:  " & vbTab & FR & NL & _
                "VBA 3:  " & vbTab & v3 & NL & _
                "VBA 4:  " & vbTab & v4 & NL & _
                "VBA 5:  " & vbTab & v5, , "Precision"
    End With
End Sub
```

---

[image: Precision]

---

> `Number precision:` **`15 digits`**
>
> `Largest  allowed positive number:` **`1.79769313486231E+308`**
>
> `Largest  allowed negative number:` **`-1E-307`**
>
> `Smallest allowed negative number:` **`-2.2251E-308`**
>
> `Smallest allowed positive number:` **`2.229E-308`**

---

More info about the differences between .Text .Value and .Value2 in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17363466/4914662)

Make sure you use .Value2 ("raw" data) if you don't work with dates or currency

Reference to MS article "[Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113)"

Comment: The new data type adds more sigfigs but still off. Is it possible the spreadsheet is wrong or the way Excel does math is different between the two

Comment: You may find [Floating-point arithmetic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113) useful