# VBA function for checking empty combobox or textbox with complex condition

Tags: excel, combobox, textbox, vba

This is my first time asking a question here, so I hope I am not missing or ignoring any of the posting rules.

Here is my qustion: I have a function that checks through a series of entry boxes, in this case comboboxes and textboxes to see that the user has entered a value. Basically it checks `If (TextBox.value & "") = ""` and returns False if it finds any of them.

I would like to modify this code so that it returns true if I have values in Textbox1 and Combobox1, or if I have values in  AAX and AAY. I only need two of the four to make my calculation. I've tried replacing the Or functions with And functions but it doesn't seem to change the functionality of the code.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Code for the function:

```
Function validate() As Boolean

    Dim ret As Boolean

    If (TextBox1.Value & "") = "" Or (ComboBox1.Value & "") = "" Or (AAX.Value & "") = "" Or (AAY.Value & "") = "" Or (ComboBox2.Value & "") = "" _
        Or (ComboBox3.Value & "") = "" Or (RB.Value & "") = "" Or (MFC.Value & "") = "" Or (MCC.Value & "") = "" Or (LB.Value & "") = "" _
        Or (TB.Value & "") = "" Or (BB.Value & "") = "" Or (ComboBox4.Value & "") = "" _
        Then
            ret = False

        Else
            ret = True

    End If

    validate = ret

End Function
```

Code that calls the function:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If Not validate() Then
       MsgBox "Fill all required fields, please"
       Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: To start with you don't need the `& ""`  You can just do `If TextBox1.Value = "" Or

Comment: do you care about the other boxes anymore? or just the 4 you referenced?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to return true if any two items have a value.

Basically you will want `If (item1 <> "" And item2 <> "") Or (item3 <>"" And item4 <> "") Then`

You can try something like this:

```
If (TextBox1.Value <> "" And ComboBox1.Value <> "") Or _
   (AAX.Value <> "" And AAY.Value <> "") Or _
   (ComboBox2.Value <> "" And ComboBox3.Value <> "") Or _ 
   (RB.Value <> "" And MFC.Value <> "") Or _
   (MCC.Value <> "" And LB.Value <> "") Or _  
   (TB.Value <> "" And BB.Value <> "") Then
        ret = False

    Else
        ret = True

End If
```

If you want to return true if **ANY** two have a value you will need a different approach. Let me know and I can provide that if it is that case.

Make note that an items `.Value` property may differ from its `.Text` property.
[What is the difference between .text, .value, and .value2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2)

Answer (score 0):

I made the assumption from what you wrote that you would like to say (in pseudo code):

> If (TextBox1 and ComboBox1 have values) **OR** (AAX and AAY have
>   values) **AND** all the rest of the boxes have values then return
>   True, otherwise return False.

This code will get you there:

```
Function validate() As Boolean

    Dim ret As Boolean

    If (Len(TextBox1.Value) <> 0 And Len(ComboBox1.Value) <> 0) _
        Or (Len(AAX.Value) <> 0 And Len(AAY.Value) <> 0) _
        And Len(ComboBox2.Value) <> 0 And Len(ComboBox3.Value) <> 0 _
        And Len(RB.Value) <> 0 And Len(MFC.Value) = 0 _
        And Len(MCC.Value) <> 0 And Len(LB.Value) <> 0 _
        And Len(TB.Value) <> 0 And Len(BB.Value) <> 0 _
        And Len(ComboBox4.Value) <> 0 Then

        ret = True

    Else

        ret = False

    End If

    validate = ret

End Function
```