# How to get the full value from an excel cell, not the displayed (rounded) value?

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I'm having an issue retrieving the exact value from an cell from a worksheet. If I open the file the cell has a decimal number which it's shown only with 4 decimals, but if I click on the particular cell, the value is different, having 6 decimals. I know it's a setting applied to the cell in order to show only 4 decimals.

Now I'm trying to retrieve the cell's data in C#, using ClosedXML.Excel, not Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, but the only thing I'm able to get is the 4 decimals value, not the "whole" one, which is a great issue as I have calculation later on and I have big differences due to the missing 2 decimals.

I have tried using `inputSheet.Worksheet.Cell(row,col).GetDouble()`, or `Convert.ToDouble(inputSheet.Worksheet.Cell(row, col).Value)`, or even to refer to the "RichText" property, or ...ToString("0.000000"), but no matter what I use, I can only retrieve the 4 decimal value instead of the full 6 decimals one.

Comment: Have you tried importing the Excel data using Oledb?

Comment: No, but I cannot use it. My current project depends a lot on CloseXLM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between .text, .value, and .value2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2)

Comment: @Eris: I don't have a value2. Is it only available in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Comment: To seems to be a bug of the library when accessing the RichText, please, check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a look at the source code of the library, here is what the `Value` getter does:

```
get
{
    string str = this.FormulaA1;
    if (!XLHelper.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
    {
        string str2;
        string sName;
        if (str[0] == '{')
        {
            str = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2);
        }
        if (str.Contains<char>('!'))
        {
            sName = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf('!'));
            if (sName[0] == '\'')
            {
                sName = sName.Substring(1, sName.Length - 2);
            }
            str2 = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('!') + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            sName = this.Worksheet.Name;
            str2 = str;
        }
        if (this._worksheet.Workbook.WorksheetsInternal.Any<XLWorksheet>(w => (string.Compare(w.Name, sName, true) == 0)) && XLHelper.IsValidA1Address(str2))
        {
            return this._worksheet.Workbook.Worksheet(sName).Cell(str2).Value;
        }
        object obj2 = this.Worksheet.Evaluate(str);
        IEnumerable enumerable = obj2 as IEnumerable;
        if ((enumerable != null) && !(obj2 is string))
        {
            using (IEnumerator enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    return enumerator.Current;
                }
            }
        }
        return obj2;
    }
    string s = this.HasRichText ? this._richText.ToString() : this._cellValue;
    if (this._dataType == XLCellValues.Boolean)
    {
        return (s != "0");
    }
    if (this._dataType == XLCellValues.DateTime)
    {
        return DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse(s));
    }
    if (this._dataType == XLCellValues.Number)
    {
        return double.Parse(s);
    }
    if (this._dataType == XLCellValues.TimeSpan)
    {
        return TimeSpan.Parse(s);
    }
    return s;
}
```

I noticed, that when it reach `string s = this.HasRichText ? this._richText.ToString() : this._cellValue;`, if you have never called `cell.RichText` (so neither viewing it with the debugger) you get the correct value, because `this.HasRichText` is false because the class has still not assigned the correct value to it.
When it(`this.HasRichText`) is `true`, you get `this._richText.ToString()`, that is the formatted number.
So, if you access the `Value` property before accessing `RichText` you should get the correct value, anyway you can get `_cellValue` using reflection, then convert it to `double` like this:

```
var theRealDoubleValue = Convert.ToDouble(yourCell.GetType().GetField("_cellValue", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(yourCell));
```

Comment: thanks so much codroipo, it's working. I could never figured it out, way above my current skills.