# ClosedXml is rounding off to 16th decimal where I am looking for higher Arithmetic precision(20th decimal place)

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am using ClosedXML to read a excel file. But for some reason closed xml is rounding the cell value which is number formatted to 16th decimal. Example the value I am getting is 0.0232080359530551 instead of 0.02320803595305504993. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861860/how-to-get-the-full-value-from-an-excel-cell-not-the-displayed-rounded-value)! article and tried it but did not work out.

Tried all these options but no success.

```
string me = string.Empty;
me = row.Cell(i).ValueCached;
me = row.Cell(i).RichText.ToString();
me = row.Cell(i).Value.ToString();
double d = 0.00000000000000000000;
d = row.Cell(i).GetDouble();
row.Cell(i).TryGetValue<double>(out d);
var fme = row.Cell(i).GetValue<double>().ToString("N30");
var fmesd = row.Cell(i).GetValue<float>().ToString("N30");
var dddsdsd = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cell(i).GetType().GetField("_cellValue", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(row.Cell(i)));
var sdfljdlf = row.Cell(i).GetValue<string>();
```

Comment: Excel's advertised number precision is 15 digits.  I don't know of any way to get a number with 20 decimal digits in Excel, unless that value is stored in Excel as a string.

Answer (score 2):

If your Datatype in Excel is Number, then Excel already rounds it to 15 digits. If it is Text, then you get the full length with `GetValue<string>()` or as number with `GetValue<decimal>()`.