# Excel 2007 VBA Range Variable References Cells Outside Assigned Range

Tags: excel, vba

I've searched everywhere but haven't been able to figure out why a range variable is able to reference cells outside the assigned range.

For example, if I write the code below:

```
 Dim Rate as Range
 Set Rate = Range("A1:A5") 

 For Each Cell In Rate
      Debug.Print Cell.Value
 Next Cell

 Range("H6").Value = Rate(6).Value
 Range("H7").Value = Rate(7).Value
```

The above routine will only print out the 5 values in "A1:A5" -- BUT the last 2 statements cause the values in "A6" and "A7" to get stored in "H6" and "H7".

Since the variable "Rate" has only been assigned to "A1:A5", why is it able to reference other cells in column A (i.e., "A6" & "A7")?

Am I doing something wrong?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks Slai.  But can you clarify how to get an error?  I'm not sure what you meant by " = Rate.Value2(7) ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong, it's just how it works. I personally like this "feature".
If you rather get an error, then you can use something like

```
 Range("H6").Value = Rate.Value2(6, 1)  ' .Value2 because .Value(6, 1)
```

because `Rate.Value2` will give a 5 by 1 variant array. Or use the `.Value` array instead of the Range:

```
 Dim Rate ' as Variant
 Rate = Range("A1:A5").Value    ' Variant/Variant(1 To 5, 1 To 1)

 Debug.Print Rate(5, 1) ' ok
 Debug.Print Rate(6, 1) ' Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range
```

or

```
 Dim Rate as Variant
 Rate = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A5"))   ' Variant/Variant(1 To 5)

 Debug.Print Rate(5) ' ok
 Debug.Print Rate(6) ' Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range
```

In your case `Rate(6)` is short for `Rate.Cells(6, 1)` which is similar to `.Offset`. For example:

```
 Debug.Print Range("C3:D4")( 1,  1).Address   ' prints "$C$3"
 Debug.Print Range("C3:D4")(-1, -1).Address   ' prints "$A$1"
```

The only way I can think of getting error with Range is to use Areas instead:

```
Dim Rate As Areas
Set Rate = Range("a1,a2,a3,a4,a5").Areas

Debug.Print Rate(5) ' ok
Debug.Print Rate(6) ' Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range
```

Comment: A couple of issues with your code: first, it should be `Next value` not `Next cell`; second, any value of `n` you pass to `Rate(n)` would fail since `Rate` will always be a **2D** array.

Comment: @Slai  Very useful to know how a Variant variable differs from Range variable in this respect.  So is there any way to cause a Range variable to generate an error if outside the assigned range (similar to what the Variant variable does)?

Comment: @Dionysus17 `Variant` is used for any type - String, Integer, Range, Object, etc. but `.Value` and `.Value2` return array of Variant. I can't think of any way to limit the cells and values that can be accessed only to the ones that are in the assigned range. You can make a function that checks for that with few `If` statements.

Comment: @Slai  Good to know.  Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @Dionysus17 I fixed few mistakes and added few more examples. I don't think that you'll like the "solution" I came up with :]

Comment: @Slai  Thanks so much for the additional examples -- and the Areas solution!  Very helpful to be introduced to .Value2, Areas, and the different ways of referencing the specified range. I have some questions.  1) Regarding "Range("C3:D4")( 1,  1).Address" -- does the offset (1,1) always refer to the first cell of the range?  Is there some reference into that describes use of that syntax as a way to specify the offset?  2) Regarding "Rate.Value2(6, 1)" -- do you mean that "Rate.Value2(1,1) should not give an error?  Any reference info that describe use of that ".Value2(1,1)" syntax?

Comment: @Dionysus17 1) `(1,1)` reffers to the first cell in the Range and is different from `.Offset(`, but I could not think of better way to describe it. You can do an internet search for `Range._Default` http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/07/07/the-strange-object/. 2) `Rate.Value2(1, 1)` to `Rate.Value2(5, 1)` would not give error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2

Comment: @Slai  Thanks, very interesting info in the links.  1) Syntax like "Range("A1")( 1, 1)"  and "Range("A1").Cells(1,1)" would never have occurred to me.  Is that something you discover by trial and error, or is there a comprehensive reference that describes all allowable syntax for all Excel objects, properties, etc.?  2) Apparently the "Rate.Value2(1,1) syntax only works for .Value2 but not .Value (e.g., "Rate.Value(1,1) gives an error).  Is that just  an arbitrary difference or is there some reasoning behind it that I missed?

Comment: mostly from experimenting and searching for examples online. There are some good topics on the SO Documentation https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/topics. Range.Value accepts a parameter, that's why https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx

Comment: @Slai    .Value / .Value2 -- looks like there are a lot of subtleties.  The info at the first link is fantastic, it's exactly what I need.  I'll definitely explore this site in more detail (just discovered it a couple of days ago).  I'm a novice at VBA, and I really appreciate your help.  Thanks again.