# Excel VBA - Convert a string Formula to an Excel Calculation in a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm just wondering if this is possible to do without a loop - In my excel sheet, in, say, `Range("A1:C10")` I have text concatenation formulas that, once concatenated, create real Excel functions.

As a stupid example, suppose I had the following in cell A1:

```
A1: ="=Sum(D"&C2&":E"&C3&")"
```

Now, I know in VBA I can do something along the following for any one specific cell:

```
Range("A1").Formula = Range("A1").Text
```

And it will convert my text formula into an Excel formula and evaluate it.

Now, what I'm curious about is, whether there a way to say, for example:

```
Range("A1:C10").Formula = Range("A1:C10").Text
```

Without looping through each cell individually?

Also, I can't use `INDIRECT()` as, unfortunately, my formulas refer to closed workbooks :/

Any ideas??

Comment: Why don't you want to loop? speed?

Comment: whats the range of `C2` and `C3` ? 1 to 10?

Comment: Try `.Value` instead of `.Text`

Comment: @CRUTER, yeah, just speed / curiosity.

Comment: @Slai, yes, it would just be a number to complete the cell reference... But that was just a stupid example to show what I meant by the string concatenation becoming a formula - My formulas are substantially more complex (external workbook references, etc).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range.Text` contains the string representation of the cell's value. The *actual* calculated value (which I suspect is what you're after) is accessed using `Range.Value` - try this:

```
Range("A1:C10").Formula = Range("A1:C10").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are trying to do, but if for example you use:

```
Range("A1:C10").Formula = "=Sum(D1:E1)"
```

then the relative references will be auto adjusted:

```
A1: =Sum(D1:E1)
A2: =Sum(D2:E2)
B1: =Sum(E1:F1)
... etc.
```

Comment: Sadly, this is not what I'm looking for - My formulas are very complex, that was just a simple example to show what I meant by the string concatenation... @MatsMug got the correct answer. But thanks for your input!!