# Faster way to run little VBA macro?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, range

I am using this little code which takes nearly 250ms to run: (`i` is the increment of a loop on lines)

```
Sheets("sheet1").Select
val1 = Sheets("sheet2").Range("D" & Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value + 1)
val2 = Sheets("sheet2").Range("E" & Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value + 1)
Sheets("sheet1").Range("G" & i).Value = val1
Sheets("sheet1").Range("O" & i).Value = val2
```

I am not sure why this is taking so long for now. 
Is it because I move data from one sheet to another? Maybe using a `variant` will be faster?

Do you have any pointers on what could I do to make it faster? (this loop is done 300-400 times so the total time is too long.)

(not sure if this has a better place here or in "code reviews", let me know if I am wrong)

Thank you for your help!

[EDIT] 
Here is the loop after your suggested changes, thank you all, that reduced the time spent by 30%.
However it is still too long for me, I have noted your suggestion to copy all the sheets `sh1` and `sh2`in a table, I will try to implement that. If you have other ideas, please keep me posted =)

```
i = 2
While sh1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    val5 = sh1.Cells(i, 1).Value2 + 1
    With sh2
        val3 = .Cells(val5, 4).Value2
        val4 = .Cells(val5, 5).Value2
    End With

    With sh1
        .Cells(i, 7).Value2 = val3
        .Cells(i, 15).Value2 = val4
    End With

    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Comment: You will want to lessen the number of calls to the worksheet by loading everything into memory arrays.

Comment: Why store the values into variables only to use those variables on the next line? You could set `Sheets("sheet1").Range("G" & i).Value = Sheets("sheet2").Range("D" & Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value + 1)`  --- but combine that with other suggestions like arrays in memory

Comment: Can you show the loop code? There are ways to make it much faster by "copying" few cells at a time instead of one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can modify as:

```
Dim sh as Worksheet, sh2 as Worksheet
Dim val1, val2
Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
With sh
    val1 = sh2.Cells(.Cells(1, i).Value2 + 1, 4)
    val2 = sh2.Cells(.Cells(1, i).Value2 + 1, 5)
    .Cells(i, 7).Value = val1
    .Cells(i, 15).Value = val2
End With
```

And further reduced (unless you need to use `val1` and `val2` elsewhere:

```
Dim sh as Worksheet, sh2 as Worksheet, r as Long
Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

With sh
    r = .Cells(1, i).Value2 + 1
    .Cells(i, 7).Value = sh2.Cells(r, 4).Value2
    .Cells(i, 15).Value = sh2.Cells(r, 5).Value2
End With
```

Additional information on how to avoid using select/activate, and proper use of variables can be found here:

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: It just went down from 250ms to 170ms, thanks! Is there a difference between `Value` and `Value2`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2

Comment: on that note, in the second code snippet above, use `sh2.Cells(r, 4).Value2` and `sh2.Cells(r, 5).Value2` and that might improve a little more.

Answer (score 3):

- Don't use .Select (you don't seem to do anything with Selection afterwards anyway)
- Store the sheets in two Variables: dim oSheet1 as Worksheet; set oSheet = Sheets("Sheet1"). Or use the code names: Sheet1 and Sheet2 (most likely)
- It might be faster to use .Cells() than .Range() to avoid the string concatenation
- If anything, avoid Variants as much as possible and declare type safe variables

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `Sheets("sheet1").Select` - it isn't doing anything in the code that you posted, and if this is in a loop it will repeatedly do nothing.

Get rid of the intermediary variables `var1` and `var2` and assign the values directly between the cells.

Use `With` blocks and stored object references to avoid repeated dereferencing of objects.  You are performing repeated object lookups in the Excel Sheets collection.

Use `.Cells` with numeric indexing instead of `Range` with string concatenation and alpha references - Excel just has to convert them back anyway.

Cache intermediate values that are going to be used repeatedly (i.e. `Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value + 1`).

Something more like:

```
'Outside loop:
Dim source As Worksheet
Dim target As Worksheet
Set source = Sheets("sheet2")
Set target = Sheets("sheet1")

'...
'Inside loop:
Dim targetRow As Long
With target
    targetRow = .Cells(i, 1).Value + 1
    .Cells(i, 7).Value = source.Cells(targetRow, 4)
    .Cells(i, 15).Value = source.Cells(targetRow, 5)
End With
```

If this still isn't fast enough, consider pulling the entire working Range into a `Variant` array and working with that instead.  When you're done, write the entire thing back in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

As @ScottCraner commented, minimizing the calls to the application is one of the keys to faster VBA macros. For example, copying the whole column at once instead of cell by cell:

```
Dim c As Long
c = Sheet2.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row - 1  ' count = last row - first row - 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = False          ' optional
Sheet1.Cells(2,  7).Resize(c).Value2 = Sheet2.Cells(2, 4).Resize(c).Value2
Sheet1.Cells(2, 15).Resize(c).Value2 = Sheet2.Cells(2, 5).Resize(c).Value2
Application.ScreenUpdating = True           ' optional
```