# Two Dimensional Array with Excel Range

Tags: arrays, excel, vb.net, multidimensional-array

### Goal

I am trying to put data into my spreadsheet using a two dimensional array which can contain one or many products.

Take a look at my two dimensional array:
[image: 2d array structure]

Now take a look at my wanted result:
[image: 2d array result]

I can't seem to correctly place the data into the Excel cells. I thought there was a 1 liner of code that could do this, but I tried a different approach and just can't seem to wrap my head around these 2d arrays... Friday can't come soon enough!

Take a look at my code:

```
If wSheet IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim colRange() As String = {"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U"}

    For i As Integer = products.GetLowerBound(0) To products.GetUpperBound(0)
        'Start at B2 ... C2 ... D2 ...
        Dim r As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = wSheet.Range(colRange(i) & "2").Resize(products.GetLength(1))
        r.Value2 = products
    Next
End If
```

This really just doesn'T work, it will just display the (0,0), (1,0) and (2,0) values to the Excel sheet... Any suggestions?

Comment: You will need to Transpose the array, and Resize the range to set Rows and Columns size. Also no need for a `For` loop.  Something like `Dim r As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = wSheet.Range("A2").Resize(products.GetLength(1), products.GetLength(0))
        r.Value2 = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application.transpose(products)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah, I knew it could've been done in a 1 liner! Lol. I swapped the columns / rows in my 2d array and tried to set that as the range.

Then it was just a matter of:

```
wSheet.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(products, 1), UBound(products, 2)).Value2 = products
```

Comment: I've a vague memory that the `.Value2` property is better, but I've forgotten exactly why. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2