# Excel vba type mismatch type 13

Tags: vba, excel

I have a created a sub to check a value of a column and clear contents of a particular range. But when selecting the value, I continuously get type mismatch error. I have tried the following four methods too. The sheet is refreshed from a sql server source and the datatype of it is string. I changed the data in the source to be a int but of now use. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
Sub abc()
    Dim var1 As String
    **var1 = Sheets(Sheet1).Cells(1, "A").Value
    var1 = Sheets(Sheet1).Cells(1, "A").Text
    var1 = Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A1").Value
    var1 = Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A1").Text**
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet1")` assuming Sheet1 is its name.

Comment: yes.. you are right. Any other thing that I'm missing in the code?

Comment: According to here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2 you should probably be using `Value2` instead of `Value` or `Text` (and definitely not the latter). I have to confess to never using it but perhaps should mend my ways.

Comment: tried that too. still the same error. It's really very strange!

Comment: Not sure what is the problem - which line errors?. You've posted four versions of basically the same line but your question refers to other things so you need to post all the code.

Comment: Note also: `Sheets("Sheet1")` is redundant, where simply `Sheet1` would suffic -- using the sheet's `CodeName` will allow the code to run even if users change the name or index of the sheet, and also avoids the possible and dreaded 1004 error of unqualified range references.

Comment: oops. To be more specific. I want to read the value of column A1 to a variable. So, I have tried using the 4 methods to read the cell value. None of them work. I've included them to show the methods I have tried. var1 = Sheets(Sheet1).Cells(1, "A").Value
    var1 = Sheets(Sheet1).Cells(1, "A").Text
    var1 = Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A1").Value
    var1 = Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A1").Text

Answer (score 0):

Try changing var1 type from string to Range or variant.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments provided. Fixed the issue. Added quotes around 
Changed var1 = Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A1").Value