# Missing decimals in named range when getting the value in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have unexpected truncation in a named range in Excel when accessing the value in VBA.

I have a cell called "temp"

When the 'temp' cell has -$0.00002 the following VBA code returns "0".

When the 'temp' cell has -$0.02 the following VBA code returns "-0.02".

```
MsgBox (Range("temp").Value)
```

Why is VBA not getting the right value in the first case? How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Use `Range("temp").Value2` See [Value v Value2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2) for more.

Comment: Thanks that was what I totally needed. :)