# Delete rows based on header name

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete a lot of rows in my Excel sheet.

My VBA is really simple:

```
Sub delNA()
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
    For i = lr To 2 Step -1 'loop thru backwards, finish at 2 for headers
        If Cells(i, "H").Text = "#N/A" Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

But my problem is that sometimes my headers are different. In this case the header BTEX (Sum) Is in H2, but sometimes that parameter is in G2 and sometimes it's in E2, so what I'm trying to do is make the VBA search for the header name, so instead of H the criteria is "BTEX (Sum)".

Is there a way to make the VBA run in the column where the value in row 2 is "BTEX (Sum)"

Comment: Are you trying to delete where the header is `BTEX (Sum)` as your text says, or where the header is `#N/A` as your code reads? Are you trying to delete a row that has a _Error_ in column H or the actual _text_ `#N/A` in column H? If you're looking for an error, use `if IsError({cell reference}) then` instead - it's much more clean. Your unqualified `Cells()` and `Rows()` references _will_ eventually get you in trouble - they implicitly refer to the `ActiveSheet` and if that ever changes (via code or user input) you'll start looking at and deleting data from the wrong worksheet.

Comment: Wait... you're trying to delete _rows_ that have an _error_ in the `BTEX (Sum)` column, but you don't always know what column `BTEX (Sum)` is in, right?

Comment: Yes FreeMan, im trying to delete rows with the text #N/A, it's not an error, the output i recive is send as a text, so using IsError is not helping in this case. And the problem is that i dont always know what column BTEX (Sum) is.

Comment: BTW- _great_ job on identifying that the deletion loop should run from the bottom up, that's the usual issue people have with deletions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Option Explicit 

Sub delNA()
  Const HEADER_TEXT As String = "BTEX (Sum)"
  Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
  Set thisSheet = ActiveSheet
  With thisSheet
    Dim myHeader As Range
    Set myHeader = .Cells.Find(What:=HEADER_TEXT, after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not myHeader Is Nothing Then  'i.e. we found the header text somewhere
      Dim headerColumn As Long
      headerColumn = myHeader.Column

      Dim lastRow As Long
'Update here:
      lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, headerColumn).End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
      Dim i As Long
      For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1 'loop thru backwards, finish at 2 for headers
'Update here:
          If IsError(.Cells(i, headerColumn).Value2) Then
            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
          End If
      Next i
    Else
      MsgBox ("Could not find a column for the header text " & HEADER_TEXT)
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

- It uses `.Find()` on the range to very quickly identify where your header column is and pops up an error message if it's *not* found (just in case)

  - NOTE: `.Find()` will use the current setting of anything in the `Find` dialog box that isn't explicitly set, and the next time you use the `Find` dialog box, the setting will be whatever they are set to by your code. i.e. the `Find` dialog box and the `.Find()` function share a common, persistent set of parameters.
- It assigns a worksheet variable to the current worksheet, just to ensure that, if this should run a while, a bored user doesn't click on another worksheet and break stuff.
- All worksheet rows explicitly reference `thisSheet` by using `.Cells()` and `.Rows()` (notice the leading `.`) because of the line: `With thisSheet`
- It uses `.Value2` instead of `.text` (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17363466/2344413) for the reason.)
- I declared `Option Explicit` at the beginning to ensure that all variables are declared before being used.

  - This is a good habit to be in as it will eliminate frustrating bugs from using `MyText` as a variable in one place and `MyTxt` as a variable somewhere else and not understanding why it isn't working.
- You now have the framework to make a more generic function by converting the `Const` declaration to a parameter that is accepted by `delNA()` and you can use it for *any* header row instead of this fixed one.

Comment: I tried running the code but i get Runtime error 13, type mismatch and highlight this part "If .Cells(i, headerColumn).Value2 = "#N/A" Then"

Comment: Hmmm... works fine for me on my current workbook. (No "#N/A" to find, but no data accidentally deleted, either...)

Comment: @MikkelAstrup - also, note that I've modified the `If` statement that actually does the deletion. I _hate_ the inline `Then` statement because I never see them. the `Rows()` there was missing the leading `.`

Comment: @MikkelAstrup - I made two updates to the code: 1) to search for the last used row in the column with the header, 2) to determine if the value `IsError()` because Excel actually treats `#N/A` as an error value, not as text when looking at it as `.Value2`

Comment: Also note: You can use `thisSheet.Columns(headerColumn).Find()` to speed up the process even further.

Comment: Amazing, after i changed to isError it runs smoothly! Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Glad to be of service, @MikkelAstrup. You may want to check out [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com/) it's a great open-source tool that will help identify a lot of the issues I pointed out above. (Disclaimer: I'm a fan, and I hang out in chat with them)

Answer (score 1):

@Mikkel Astrup you first just use an for loop to find the col index you are looking for, in this case col index of the cell in row 2 have value "BTEX (Sum)"

```
Dim lColumn,indexCol As Long
dim ws as worksheet
dim headerKey as string
set ws = thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1")
lColumn = ws.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
headerKey =  "BTEX (Sum)"
for indexCol = 1 to lColumn step 1 
if ws.cells(2,indexCol).value = headerKey then
' your code '  indexCol is the index of col you are looking for'
exit for ' exit the loop now
end if
Next
```