# Type mismatch with cell value "#N/A"

Tags: vba, excel

Why is it when I try:

```
MsgBox (Cells(1, 1).Value)
```

The cases are as follows:

1. When I write #123 in cell A1, I get #123 from MsgBox.
2. When I write #N/A in cell A1, I get error type mismatch?

I know `#N/A` is the default error cell value in Excel, but I have manually input this value, does VBA not take my manual input of `#N/A` as a string?

Comment: You can try replacing `.Value` with `.Text`. The value of the cell is an error, but if you are wanting to see the textual representation of the cell, you would use `.Text` instead.

Answer (score 1):

[Charles Williams' post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17363466/5781745) provided a good explanation of the differences between the usage of `.Value` and `.Text`.

In response to the question in your comment, there are many different ways to replace cells. One method would be to use an `If...Then` statement, such as:

```
If Cell().Text = "#N/A" Then
    ' Your code
End If
```

You can apply the above for use in a `For Each...Next` statement:

```
Dim Cel as Range
For Each Cel In Worksheets(1).Cells
    If Cel.Text = "#N/A" Then
        Cel.Value = 0
    End If
Next Cel
```

Also, if you were wanting to look for all errors (such as more than just the `#N/A`), you could use `IsError()`:

```
Dim Cel As Range
For Each Cel In Worksheets(1).Cells
    If IsError(Cel) Then
        Cel.Value = 0
    End If
Next Cel
```

I might add that checking the entire worksheet is time-consuming. It would be wise to add some method of exiting your For statement once you have checked the cells you are needing to, such as utilizing `UsedRange` for example.

Comment: Thanks for that (really great answer!), without that I believe it just crashes my worksheet!
I am just thinking, why is it when I use:  
`kbd>Dim i as Integer`  
`For i = 0 To 25`  
`If Cells(1 + i, 1).Text Like "#N/A" Then`  
`Cells(1 + i, 1).Value = 1`  
`End If`  
`Next i`  

It doesn't work for me?

Comment: @Ross Replace `Like` with `=`. The `#` in your `#N/A` is [reserved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) for a wildcard of a number between `0 - 9` when using the `Like Operator`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been so confused for the past two hours... but this works! One more Question Why would in this case `Like` not work? - Is it because `Like` only looks for strings and in this case, the cell value of "#N/A" is not considered a string? (Nevermind that makes so much sense now....)!