# Deleting a text in multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel

i cant manage to properly delete a text in multiple cells in a column in Excel.
The sheet looks like this:

```
123 456 7|
123 456 7|
123 456 7|
```

I just want to get rid of 123 456. (By the way, 123 456 7 are all in one cell)

I think there's an error in my code:

```
Sub RemoveText()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A1:A3")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Text, "123 456", "", Count:=2)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `cell.Text` with `cell.Value`?

Comment: Isn't that the same?

Comment: @trill https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2

Comment: I just copied and pasted your Sub here and it worked. What kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a loop or `.value` vs. `.text`. Simple one liner will do:

```
Range("A1:A3").Replace "123 456","",xlPart
```

Be mindful that the replace function can tie up resources when used on formula heavy and or data intensive ranges.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `cell.Value` also within the replace function

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A3")

For Each cell In rng
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "123 456", "")
Next cell

End Sub
```