# How to export a specific area of an excel file and import it to the another excel file?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I have been working on a project that I need to export a specific area of an excel file such as (A1:C3) and import the values of each cell to another excel file (A2:C4).

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

If it is impossible to do it directly by exporting an area as a tuple and importing it to the other file,
I have accomplished to export values of the cells as a list(consist of 9 values of the A1:C3 area). Since there is no specific number of row or columns I couldn't import the values into the individual cells with for loops.

girde = [a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3] #list of values in A1:C3

import_file.active['A2'] = girde[1] #importfile active sheet cell(A1) = a1

import_file.active['B2'] = girde[2]

## works well but the area can be larger so I need a general code

Comment: in excel you can use copy / paste, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50776026/4961700

Comment: With a different approach, it works well. Thank you!

Comment: If that answer helped, give it a vote :) but glad it works for you.