# VBA Sheet Names with Loops

Tags: excel, vba

I have a few sheets in a workbook. They are each called Sheet (1), Sheet (2) etc.

I want to run a loop to go through each sheet and highlight a particular cell.

I have tried setting this up in vba, but can't seem to work out how to loop through the sheets.

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 13

Sheets("Sheet (" & i & ")").Columns("L").Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft

Next i
```

However, this doesn't seem to loop through each of the sheets.

Comment: Are you trying to delete column `L` from every sheet ?

Comment: Works for me.  Though you may want to qualify which workbook the sheets are in, assuming it's `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Try `Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet (" & i & ")").Columns("L").Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft`

Comment: Thanks all, defining the Activeworkbook helped.

Comment: @Mikku why use ActiveWorkbook? That's asking for trouble..

Comment: I know it's not Ideal, But we don't know where the Macro is Saved, maybe in Personal Workbook or an Addin. Most probable scenario for anyone to run a Macro is after being on that WorkBook.

Comment: Have a look at defining workbook names, I use wbtarget & wbmaster... : https://stackoverflow.com/q/50776026/4961700

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through sheets like below :

```
Sub LoopSheets()
 
    Dim Sh As Worksheet

    For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Sh.Columns("L").Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
    Next Sh

End Sub
```