# With - copy paste

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy/cut - paste multiple tables in the same sheet from a certain range a few lines down. for some reason, if i use the code blow it will only select the range B24 and not paste. Tried with the ranges outside the with and it works. not sure why. pls help

```vb
Dim NQSwks As Worksheet
Dim lastrowStatus As Long
With NQSwks
        lastrowStatus = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("B11:W" & lastrowStatus).Cut
    .Range("B24").PasteSpecial
    .Range("B2:W9").Copy
    .Range("B11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Range("B2:W9").Copy
    .Range("B11").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    .Range("C14:C18").Copy
    .Range("G5:G9").PasteSpecial
    .Range("B2") = "week " & WeekOfQuarter & " for week " & WeekOfQuarter + 1 & " OL"
```

Comment: Have a look at this, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50776026/4961700

Comment: `Cut` has a `Destination` parameter so try `.Range("B11:W" & lastrowStatus).Cut .Range("B24")`