# Copying data from a CSV to and XLSX file using VBA in Excel 365

Tags: excel, csv, office365, copy-paste

I am trying to create a macro that copies all the data from a csv file to the workbook that executed the macro.

I got the code below from [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_sC6Uwtwxk)

It appears to copy, but fails to paste.

I have tested this with .csv, .xlsx files; and combinations of sheet names and numbers.

I suspect it can't find the current workbook, because I have save the Marco to the Personal Macro file excel generates.

Can someone please advise how I can correct the paste location?

```
Sub AS_and_L_Reports()
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:P20").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Close True
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Check out the answers I was given here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50776026/4961700

Comment: Lots of different methods shown on here to get data from 1 sheet to another - avoiding copy & paste can increase the speed...