# Path that opens file on PC fails on Mac

Tags: excel, vba

This macro works as intended on my PC and co-worker's PC.

When sent to a client, who is using a Mac they are getting a print error 1004.

The debugger points to this line of code.

```vb
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, _
  FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sila Total Rewards Statement_" & SSDest.Range("B9").Value, _
  Quality:=xlQualityStandard
```

Full code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Create_PDFs_Loop_Updated()

Dim FileName As String
Dim Startcell As Long

Let Startcell = 13
'13 indicates the row where employee IDs start (A13 in Sheet1 [Employee Details])

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .StatusBar = "Running Macro..."
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

Do Until Sheet1.Range("A" & Startcell).Value = ""
    
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        '.Zoom = False
        '.FitToPagesWide = 1
        '.FitToPagesTall = 1
        .BottomMargin = 10
        .TopMargin = 10
        .RightMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)
        .LeftMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)
    End With
    
    Sheet1.Range("A" & Startcell).Copy SSDest.Range("C9:D9")
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Client Total Rewards Statement_" & SSDest.Range("B9").Value, Quality:=xlQualityStandard
    Startcell = Startcell + 1
    
Loop

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .StatusBar = ""
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: File path separator on Mac is / not \

Comment: / also works on Windows...  Or you can use `Application.PathSeparator`

Comment: Have a look at how I got files on my macs (macbook pro and iMac): https://stackoverflow.com/q/50776026/4961700

Comment: Thank you Tim Williams, changing the file path separator from \ to / did the trick!