# Copy a range of cells in a row and paste same row/range

Tags: excel, vba, office365, copy-paste

Thats my data. I want to copy B2:M9 and insert it to P2. Furher, I want to copy B13:M20 and paste it to P2. Then I want to copy B24:M31 and paste it to P2 and so on.
Does anyone have an idea how I can do it?

[image: My data]

Thank you!

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Please have a look on the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Have a look at the q&a here, give it a vote if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50776026/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub copypasta()

Dim nb_iter as Integer 'Number of ranges you have to copy
nb_iter = 3 'for example
Dim step as Integer
step = 0 

for k = 1 to nb_iter
Range("B" & step + 2, "M" & step + 9).Copy
Range("P2").PasteSpecial , Paste:=xlPasteValues
step = step + 11 'you are adding 11 to both row numbers for each iteration
Next k

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt:

```
Sub Copypasta()
  Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To 31
    Range("B" & 2 + i, "M" & 9 + i).Copy
    Range("P2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next i

End Sub
```