# Excel Copy/ Paste Special with selected sheets not working

Tags: excel, vba

This first routine works fine to run through all of the sheets, and creates static pages in an new spreadsheet

```
Sub StaticSheets()
Dim wbStatic As Workbook, wbDynamic As Workbook, DynamicName As Variant, _
DynamicPath As Variant, StaticName As Variant, curSheetName As String, curStaticSheet As Worksheet, curDynSheet As Worksheet
Dim wbs As Workbooks

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wbDynamic = ActiveWorkbook
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set wbs = Workbooks()
DynamicPath = wbDynamic.Path
DynamicName = fso.GetBaseName(wbDynamic.Name)
StaticName = DynamicName & "-Static"
Set wbStatic = Workbooks.Add
For Each curDynSheet In wbDynamic.Sheets
    curSheetName = curDynSheet.Name
    wbStatic.Sheets.Add(After:=wbStatic.Sheets(wbStatic.Sheets.Count)).Name = curSheetName
   
    curDynSheet.Activate
    Range("A1:AZ400").SpecialCells(12).Copy 'Copy visible Cells only
    
    With wbStatic.Worksheets(curSheetName).Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        .PasteSpecial xlFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
  Next
  wbStatic.SaveAs Filename:=DynamicPath & "\" & StaticName
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End Sub
```

When I try the following code with just a few sheets selected, I get various errors depending on what I've tried for curDynSheet.select and curDynSheet.activate, but nothing is working.  The code below is giving a 1004 Paste Special method of Range class failed.  I'm guessing that  the copy method failed first, but I'm not sure why.

```
Sub StaticSelectedSheets()
Dim wbStatic As Workbook, wbDynamic As Workbook, DynamicName As Variant, _
DynamicPath As Variant, StaticName As Variant, curSheetName As String, curStaticSheet As Worksheet, curDynSheet As Worksheet
Dim wbs As Workbooks
Dim sheetArray As Variant


Set wbDynamic = ActiveWorkbook
Set sheetArray = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set wbs = Workbooks()
DynamicPath = wbDynamic.Path
DynamicName = fso.GetBaseName(wbDynamic.Name)
StaticName = DynamicName & "-Static"
Set wbStatic = Workbooks.Add
For Each curDynSheet In sheetArray
    curSheetName = curDynSheet.Name
    wbStatic.Sheets.Add(After:=wbStatic.Sheets(wbStatic.Sheets.Count)).Name = curSheetName
    curDynSheet.Activate
    curDynSheet.Select
    curDynSheet.Range("A1:AZ400").SpecialCells(12).Copy 'Copy visible Cells only
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    With wbStatic.Worksheets(curSheetName).Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        .PasteSpecial xlFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
  Next
  wbStatic.SaveAs Filename:=DynamicPath & "\" & StaticName
  End Sub
```

I've tried multiple options with how ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets is handled. The SheetArray seems to be filling out, and I get the first new sheet tab created correctly with the right name...it's just the cut and paste special stuff that isn't working right.

Comment: Have a look at this, if one helps give it a vote: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50776026/4961700

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell.

```
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
```

Is cancelling your copy command, so there is nothing to paste, therefore the paste error.