# VBA to prevent worksheet formatting when copying and pasting?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet in which the user will be doing lots of copying and pasting of values. I want the user to be able to copy and paste values but ***without*** changing the formatting of the sheet. I'm wondering if this can first be achieved with protection settings, and if not, if this can be achieved with VBA?

Many thanks.

Comment: Use paste.special, something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50776026/4961700

Answer (score 1):

The build-in function of Excel would be to ask the user to use `PasteSpecial` and copy only the values. However, users tend to not follow that.

What you could do is to create a Change routine that saves the copied values into memory, issue an Undo-Command that will revert the last action, including formatting, and then write back the saved values into the cells. Put the code into the worksheet module of that sheet:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    ' Save modified value
    Dim v
    ReDim v(1 To Target.Areas.Count)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Target.Areas.Count
        v(i) = Target.Areas(i).Value2
    Next i
    ' Undo last action
    Application.Undo
    
    ' Copy only the values of the last modification
    For i = 1 To Target.Areas.Count
        Target.Areas(i).Value2 = v(i)
    Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste values in one line of VBA

```
Range("B1:B3").Select: Selection.Copy: Range("P1").Select: Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues: Application.CutCopyMode = False: Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: And how will you trigger that code?