# My ctrl v is not working once i copy data from one xlsm file to another xlsm file in macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel macro file.I am trying copy one xlsm file data to paste it another xlsm file.
Its simple right?
I can able to do it from clipborad.(ctrl c)is working for copy but problem is when i paste
copy data to another xlsm file by using (ctrl v) is not working.
i know its happend some of reason like as :
1.once sheet is protect
2.once cleapboard is clearing by automatically

could you please help me

actually i dont know why paste (ctrl v ) is not working for my xlsm file

Comment: You've added `VBA` as a tag.  Are you trying to copy and paste using code, or manually pressing Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V on the keyboard?  If you're using code can you edit your question and post the code please?  The Edit button is just below the tags.

Comment: See this for another method of sending data, and give it a vote if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50776026/4961700

Comment: Instead Ctrl+V right-click and check if Paste Options are available or not

Comment: @Blackcat paste option is not available once right click
but i am able to paste data from clipboard

Comment: You probably have an event code that clears the clipboard in one of the files.

Comment: @Andreas you are right !!
I solved the problem by just adding one line of the condition like this:
if application.cutcopymode =0 then
"my code"
end if

Answer (score 0):

> Finally, i solved it by adding one line of the If condition code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
 **If application.cutcopymode =0** 'solution of my problem'
If ActiveSheet.Name = "aaa" Then
    'Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)" 'code to hide ribbon.
Else
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)" 'code to show ribbon.
**End If**. End if. End Sub
```