# Macro Copy and Paste to new Sheets. Running File

Tags: excel, vba

I want to paste the filtered data from "ChangeList" Sheet to "Status" Sheets without overriding the old data pasted. However, when I tried below formula it is not pasting to "B7" the data was pasted in a different rows.
E.G 1. B8 from ChangeList Sheet to B7 Status Sheet
2. C8 from Changelist Sheet to C7 Status Sheet and So on

```
Sub paste2()
' paste2 Macro
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHANGELIST").Range("$A$5:$AJ$106").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Submitted"
    Dim lastRow As Long
' this finds the number of the last row
   lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   
    Sheets("CHANGELIST").Select Range("B8:B1000").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    
    Sheets("STATUS").Select
    Range("B7").Select
    Cells(lastRow, 2).PasteSpecial
```

to Paste the Data from ChangeList Sheet B8 to Sheet Status B7 and new data will be pasted in a new row if there is additional filtered data in changelist sheet

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/50776026/4961700 for some paste methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure which is the active sheet or what is the influence of the place of the script to the references, always fully qualify the range object.

```
Sub paste2()
' paste2 Macro

Set targetsheet = Worksheets("Status")   'added

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHANGELIST").Range("$A$5:$AJ$106").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Submitted"
    Dim lastRow As Long
' this finds the number of the last row
   lastRow = targetsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row   'modified
   
    Sheets("CHANGELIST").Select Range("B8:B1000").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    
    Sheets("STATUS").Select
    Range("B7").Select       
    targetsheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).PasteSpecial         'modified
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check for the last row on both sheets and only take what's necessary to the right row:

```
Sub paste2()
' paste2 Macro
    Dim wsChange As Worksheet, wsStatus As Worksheet
    Dim lrChange As Long, lrStatus As Long
    Set wsChange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHANGELIST")
    Set wsStatus = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("STATUS")
    With wsChange
        On Error Resume Next: .ShowAllData: On Error GoTo 0  'edit this out if you want to keep previous filters
        lrChange = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A5:AJ" & lrChange).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Done"
        Dim rng As Range 'avoid using Select
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = .Range("B6:D" & lrChange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            lrStatus = wsStatus.Range("B" & wsStatus.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            rng.Copy wsStatus.Range("B" & lrStatus + 1)
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Else
            MsgBox "None found/copied over"
            .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Notice how I avoided using Select like Dominique already linked in the comments.
Not sure how you expected to copy the C-column as well when you don't have it in your copying range, if you need more columns adjust it as such:

`Set rng = .Range("B6:B" & lrChange)` becomes `Set rng = .Range("B6:AJ" & lrChange)`

I had the some initial values set up in the STATUS sheet, then ran it once with only B to be copied, afterwards B to D

[image]

Also note that I changed the starting row to be looked at for specialcells from B8 to B6 since I figured this would be some hard-coded number that came out of the filtered action, i.e. B8 was the first cell with Submitted in.