# Getting hash instead the actual value from excel in PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I want to get data from a column in excel sheet. In my case it's the 3rd one. I use a for loop in order to scan all the cells and I have the following column :

```
1,724.87
1,560.00
18,109.61
64.37
4,898.22
1,784.47
43,430.30
```

When I use the `WorkSheet.Cells.Item($x,3).Text` function in the loop to get the content of each cell, I get the following :

```
1,724.87
1,560.00
#######
64.37
4,898.22
1,784.47
#######
```

The ####### can be seen in the .xls file when I open it in excel. When I expand the width of the column it shows the actual number again. So I assume that it reads it as it is. What can be done in order to get the actual number?

Comment: that's wierd. You probably can solve this issue and many others or You can start using ImportExcel module.

Comment: Can you try `WorkSheet.Cells.Item($x,3).Value`?

Comment: `WorkSheet.Cells.Item($x,3).Value` keeps it the same

Comment: Before you read the text from that column, use: `WorkSheet.Cells.Item($x,3).Columns.Autofit()`

Comment: Well it does helps. Question is what happens when I won't be able to know if a column has hashtags? There is an option to auto-fit for the whole sheet?

Comment: `WorkSheet.Columns.Autofit` should be for the whole sheet. Just wondering, would it work, if you try `WorkSheet.Cells.Item($x,3).Value2`?

Comment: Interesting, seems to be that `WorkSheet.Cells.Item($x,3).Value2` works. Found this thread that makes more sense regarding the difference between the 2 :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue with `WorkSheet.Cells.Item($x,3).Text` is that `.Text` will represent anything shown on the screen in the cell. In my case is #######
To show the actual value of the cell ,should be using `WorkSheet.Cells.Item($x,3).Value2`. More difference between .Value, .Value2 and .Text can be found in this post :
[What is the difference between .text, .value, and .value2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2)