# VBA: Purpose of .Text and .Formula (when writing)?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty new to VBA and I was wondering if there's a point to distinguish between Range().Value and Range().Formula/Text when writing data to cells. I've tried it and it seems to me that it works just as well using .Value.

I know that they return different things when used to read out data

Comment: You can highlight a word in the VBE, and press F1 and it will display a lot of information for you. [`range.Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.text) and [`range.Formula`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formula)

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs-I did not know that, I feel very informed right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between .text, .value, and .value2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2)