# VBA excel extra spaces in concatenation

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I have a VBA code in which I have to loop through a certain range and fill it using some concatenation but my VBA code is adding **undesired blank spaces**. For example, let's assume the following example:

```
code = "NV"
ac = "Curncy"

With wsNew

Set rng = .Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown))

For Each r In rng
    
    If r.Value = 17 Or r.Value = 18 Or r.Value = 19 Then
        
        r.Offset(, 1) = code + r.Offset(, -1).Value + Str(Right(r.Value, 1)) + " " + Str(r.Value) + _
        " " + ac
    
    Else
    
        r.Offset(, 1) = code + r.Offset(, -1).Value + Str(Right(r.Value, 1)) + _
        " " + ac
    
    End If

Next r

End With
```

For the first cell (`r` variable in the example), I have `r.Value = 18` and `r.offset(,-1).Value = U` and I was expecting to obtain a value of `NVU8 18 Curncy` for my `r.Offset(, 1)`. Instead, the code is adding spaces and I get `NVU 8  18 Curncy` with one space between U and 8 (to be removed) and 2 spaces between 8 and 18 instead of just one.

Comment: Use Cstr and not Str.  ALso Use & for concatenation and not +.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`Str`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) docs:

> When numbers are converted to strings, a leading space is always reserved for the sign of number. If number is positive, the returned string contains a leading space and the plus sign is implied.

Don't use `Str`, and use `&` to concatenate, instead of `+`. `&` forces string concatenation of two expressions.

```
r.Offset(, 1).Value = code & r.Offset(, -1).Value & Right(r.Value, 1) & " " & r.Value & _
        " " & ac
```

Answer (score 2):

BigBen gave the solution

here's a possible enhacement (see comments) of your code

```
With wsNew

    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown)) ' <-- use dots (".") before all range references !
    
    For Each r In Rng
        
        Select Case r.Value2 ' <-- "Select Case" syntax  can make it more readable and maintanable then a multiple If Then Else
            Case 17, 18, 19
            
                r.Offset(, 1).Value2 = code & r.Offset(, -1).Value2 & Right$(r.Value2, 1) & " " & r.Value2 & " " & ac
        
            Case Else
        
                r.Offset(, 1).Value2 = code & r.Offset(, -1).Value2 & Right$(r.Value2, 1) & " " & ac
        
        End If
    
    Next

End With
```

Use of `Value2` property gets rid for possible unwanted pieces (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2#:%7E:text=Text%20is%20the%20formatted%20cell%27s,stripped%20of%20any%20extraneous%20information.))

Comment: Thanks for the dot advice... and I forgot about the Select Case statement in VBA, duly noted!