# Reading Values with % from Excel Using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a requirement where I have to read data from Excel and write it to another excel.

In my excel I have one column as below screeshot.

[image]

When I read it Using powershell using the below command

```
$WorkSheet.Cells.Item(12,47).Value2
```

The value 0.9% is read as 0.00931.Is it possible that I can read the value as 0.9%

Comment: multiply it by 100. Why are you using powerpoint to do this?

Comment: @Solar Mike I want to read the value as "0.9%" .And i am using powershell not PowerPoint

Comment: So why does the title specify Powerpoint?

Comment: 0.00931 = 0.931%. Nothing wrong with that. Just multiply by 100 when printing and you'll get the percent value

Comment: Perhaps also have a look at [What is the difference between .text, .value, and .value2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2)