# VBA Delete Row contains specific exact word

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

I want to delete rows from Excel if Column A contains "string1" as shown in the following table:

| A1 | B1 |
| --- | --- |
| string1 string2 | string3 string4 |
| string5 string6 | string7 string8 |

I'm using the below code:

```
 Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim pos As Integer
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    
    For i = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        pos = InStr(LCase(rng.Item(i).Value), LCase("string1"))
        If pos > 0 Then
            rng.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

The problem is that if the Column A contains "string11" not "string1" it's also deleting the row.
Any advice, please?
Thanks

Comment: `if LCase(rng(i).text) = "string1" then`

Comment: But probably better to use `.Value`, not `.Text`.

Comment: @BigBen why the `.Value` is better?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2 Well this argues for `.Value2` but in any case the first paragraph explains a potential pitfall of `.Text`. Probably won't really matter if OP's data is all strings, but I guess I tend to avoid `.Text`.

Comment: @АлексейР The problem is that this "=" will not work if there is another word in the cell. I think we need to use some thing like "contains"

Comment: Try to use Split() or RegExp

Comment: @АлексейР How please?

Answer (score 3):

With `Split()` (tested; not optimized):

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    
    For i = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        For Each w In Split(LCase(rng(i).Value))
            If w = "string1" Then
                rng(i).EntireRow.Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next i
End Sub
```

### Edit 2

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim rng As Range, i As Long, w, arr
    arr = Array("string1", "string2", "string3")
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    
    For i = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        For Each w In Split(LCase(rng(i).Value))
            If IsNumeric(Application.Match(w, arr, 0)) Then
                rng(i).EntireRow.Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @АлексейР.. This is really helped.. instead of "=" can we search for in a list of strings, like: If w in ("string1, "string2", "string3")?

Comment: You can use Application.Match(w,array(),0)

Comment: @ АлексейР..  Thanks for answering, but I'm a little bit new to VBA.. How to put this is the code you put above, please?

Comment: See Edit2 with `Application.Match()`

Answer (score 1):

Try combining the "found in string" with "string is same length". Like this:

```
Sub DeleteRows()

   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
   
   For i = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
       pos = InStr(LCase(rng.Item(i).Value), LCase("delete"))
       If pos > 0 And (Len(rng.Item(i).Value) = Len(Lcase("delete"))) Then
           rng.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
       End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

Or if you wanted to compare the entire cell contents you could just simplify it to:

```
Sub DeleteRows()

   Dim rng As Range
   Dim pos As Integer
   Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
   
   For i = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
       If LCase(rng.Item(i).Value) = LCase("delete") Then rng.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not simply use `=` or `StrComp` instead of `InStr`?

Comment: Because original solution (retained) was created with minimal changes to the OP's original code. Also now edited to add a simpler solution for if the OP wants to compare to entire cell contents instead of a word.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the pos variable, just compare the values in If statement!

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim pos As Integer
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    
    For i = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        If rng.Item(i).Value = "delete" Then
            rng.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```