# How do I keep newline spacing in a cell when putting cell value into VBA and moving to Outlook?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, newline

How is it going,

I am trying to make a super simple automated email script that sends quick update emails on project statuses. Trying not to loop to death, I put all update comments in one cell with a newline char(10) for each point. Example:
[image: Excel Cells being put into Email]

When I try to translate that into VBA, I lose the Char(10):

[image: Output in Email]

Below is the section I am struggling with

```
             strUpdateNotes = Range("D" & i).Text
                    olNewMail.HTMLBody = "Happy Friday!" & _
                                        "<br />" & _
                                        "<br />" & _
                                        "Weekly Project Update!" & _
                                        "<br />" & _
                                        "<br />" & _
                                        "Current Comments on the project:" & _
                                        "<br />" & _
                                        strUpdateNotes & _
                                        "<br />" & _
                                        "<br />" & _
                                        "Let me know if you have any questions. Have a fantastic weekend!"
```

Is there a way to keep the newline char(10) from the cell to help with readability in the email?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming it's actually JUST a `Chr(10)` then - `strUpdateNotes = Replace(Range("D" & i).Text, vbLf, "<br />")` - other possibilities: `strUpdateNotes = Replace(Range("D" & i).Text, vbCr, "<br />")` or `strUpdateNotes = Replace(Range("D" & i).Text, vbCrLf, "<br />")`

Comment: Worked like a freaking charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: **1.** Avoid the use of `.Text`. You may want to see [What is the difference between .text, .value, and .value2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2) **2.** Fully qualify the range `Range("D" & i).Value2`. Without qualifying, it will refer to activesheet, which may or may not be the worksheet you think it is. For example `Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's actually JUST a `Chr(10)` then

```
strUpdateNotes = Replace(Range("D" & i).Text, vbLf, "<br />")
```

other possibilities:

```
strUpdateNotes = Replace(Range("D" & i).Text, vbCr, "<br />")
```

or

```
strUpdateNotes = Replace(Range("D" & i).Text, vbCrLf, "<br />")
```

Comment: Super quick, and worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: Done, sorry for the delay!