# Filter worksheet with 2 sets of data and copy some columns into new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

I got help with the code below. I have a worksheet with 2 sets of data. Each data set has its own headers.

My intentions:

1. Filter the first data set (only) using InputBox and copy multiple columns
   ("A:A, C:C, E:F, U:W, Y:Z, AB:AC") into another worksheet, which I am also naming using InputBox.
   **The code does not stop at lastrow of first data set**
2. Divide the values in column Q of the new sheet by 0.85.
   **(the formula in the code errors at the point)**
3. Extract the new sheet and save on the desktop.
   **Not yet written in the code**

```vb
Sub FilterAZ()

Dim Cust As String
Dim newSh As String
Dim Az As Range
Dim filterAz As Range
Dim amount As Range

Cust = Application.InputBox("Enter filter criteria, (e.g *BCIC*)") ''' Set the filter criteria
Cust = Trim(Cust) ''' to deal with unwillingly entered extra spaces

''' Add a new sheet and rename it as per entered criteria
newSh = Application.InputBox("Enter SheetName, (eg. Az_BCIC)") '' Set the new sheet name
newSh = Trim(newSh) '' to deal with unwillingly entered extra spaces
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Usage")).Name = newSh

    With Sheets("Usage") ''' Change the sheet name accordingly
        .Activate
        Set Az = .UsedRange '' Set the table range
        .Range("A:A,C:C,E:F,U:W,Y:Z,AB:AC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        With Az
            .Range("A2").AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Cust
            ''' Show only the columns we want
            Set filterAz = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            ''' Transfer the filtered table
            filterAz.Copy Sheets(newSh).Range("A2")
        End With

        With Sheets(newSh)
            .Activate
            For Each amount In.Range(Cells(3,"Q"), Cells(Rows.Count,"Q").End(xlUp))
                amount.Value = Round(CDec(amount.value)/0.85, 2)
            Next amount
            .Columns("Q:Q").NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00_ ;[Red]-[$$-en-US]#,##0.00 "
            .Columns.AutoFit
            .Range("A1").Activate
        End With

        '''Restore the raw data to its original state
        .Activate
        .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        .ShowAllData
        .Range("A2").AutoFilter
        .Range("A1").Activate
    End With

    MsgBox "Completed"
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: for the error part try replacing amount.Value = Round(CDec(amount.value)/0.85, 2) with amount.Value2 = Round(CDec(amount.value2)/0.85, 2) (for difference between value and value2 check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/17363466/14849657 )

Comment: I tried it still returned error. Any reason why it would work once then return error?

Comment: I included If Isnumeric(Amount.value) Then, and seems to now working,

Answer (score 0):

I updated to the below and it works perfectly.

```vb
Sub FilterAZ()

Dim Cust As String
Dim newSh As String
Dim Az As Range
Dim filterAz As Range
Dim amount As Range

Cust = Application.InputBox("Enter filter criteria, (e.g *BCIC*)") ''' Set the filter criteria
Cust = Trim(Cust) ''' to deal with unwillingly entered extra spaces

''' Add a new sheet and rename it as per entered criteria
newSh = Application.InputBox("Enter SheetName, (eg. Az_BCIC)") '' Set the new sheet name
newSh = Trim(newSh) '' to deal with unwillingly entered extra spaces
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Usage")).Name = newSh

    With Sheets("Usage") ''' Change the sheet name accordingly
        .Activate
        **Set Az = .UsedRange.CurrentRegion** '' Set the table range
        **Set lastCell = Az(Az.Rows.Count, Az.Columns.Count)**
        .Range("A:A,C:C,E:F,U:W,Y:Z,AB:AC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        With Az
            .Range("A2").AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Cust
            ''' Show only the columns we want
            Set filterAz = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            ''' Transfer the filtered table
            filterAz.Copy Sheets(newSh).Range("A2")
        End With

        With Sheets(newSh)
            .Activate
            For Each amount In.Range(Cells(3,"Q"), Cells(Rows.Count,"Q").End(xlUp))
                **If IsNumeric(amount.Value) Then
                **amount.Value = amount.value/0.85**
            Next amount
            .Columns("Q:Q").NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00_ ;[Red]-[$$-en-US]#,##0.00 "
            .Columns.AutoFit
            .Range("A1").Activate
        End With

        '''Restore the raw data to its original state
        .Activate
        .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        .ShowAllData
        .Range("A2").AutoFilter
        .Range("A1").Activate
    End With

    MsgBox "Completed"
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).