# check if cell value is an integer

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to check if a value of a cell is an integer (number without comma) or decimal (number with comma).
I tried:

1.)

```
IsNumeric(.Cells(row, column).Value)
```

-> true also for decimal

2.)

```
IsNumeric(CInt(.Cells(row, column).Value))
```

-> Types incompatiple

3.)

```
If CInt(.Cells(row, column).Value) / .Cells(row, column).Value = 1
```

-> Types incompatiple

Comment: Try previously checking if is numeric.

Comment: try the mod() function

Comment: `If (CInt(.Cells(row, column).Value)/2=.Cells(row, column).Value/2) Then...Else`

Comment: VBA has Integer and Decimal types but I suspect that this is not what you mean.  So please clarify what you mean by Decimal and Integer.

Answer (score 3):

The MOD() function like this:

```
=MOD(A1,1)
```

will return 0 if integer and a value greater than 0 if the number has a decimal.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a numeric value from Excel to VBA, the value is always passed as `Double`, therefore the check for `VarType` will not work.

Try the following function: It first checks if the value is numeric at all. If yes, it checks if the integer-part of the number is equal to the number itself. It uses  `CLng` to avoid numeric overflows.

```
Function isInteger(c As Variant) As Boolean
    If Not IsNumeric(c) Then Exit Function
    isInteger = (c = CLng(c))
End Function
```

**Update** After freeflow's comment, I did some tests, see image.
It seems that the formatting of a cell doesn't impact the type that is passed to VBA - except if it is a Date. The number `44614` shown as value is in fact the formula `=Today()` (so today's date, without time). Only when the cell is formatted as Date, the value is passed as a Date rather than a number.
In all cases, when a number is passed, it is passed as Double.
The column `IsInteger` shows the result of the Function above.

(With *passed* I mean that a variant is passed containing a vartype of...)

[image]

Comment: This is working, but returning also true for dates e.g. 31.12.2022

Comment: True: A date in Excel is nothing more than a number - just displayed differently.

Comment: Excel always passes back a Variant.  Don't be fooled by implicit conversions. .Value returns the formatted output of the cell so in the case of a date vartype will correctly return a type of vbDate if the cell if formatted as a date.

Comment: @freeflow It's clear that Excel passes Variants. `.Value` passes the real value of a cell, the formatted value is in `.Text` and is always a String. I don't think there is an implicit conversion going on, Excel really stores numbers as Double (including a Date).

Comment: No. Value passes the formatted output as a number, string, or date. Value 2 passes the actual value.  I checked the documentation on this and verified it by getting different values for vartype for string, date and numbers.

Comment: Disagree. Value and Value2 result in the same *except* for currency and date, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2/17363466#17363466. And a Date in VBA and Excel is a Double, just the VarType is set differently (but the binary representation is the same).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method would be to use the vartype method with a select case structure

```
Select case VarType(.cells(row,column).value)

    Case vbInteger, vbDecimal

        <do stuff>

    case Else

        <Do other stuff>

end select
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the VarType of a numeric cell is always 5 (double)

Comment: Very likely correct.  I use Excel for maybe 30 minutes a year so don't rely on my output.  Just change the case statement to use whatever numeric vartypes are used internally by excel.

Comment: The point is that no matter if you have a value 1 or 1.5 in a cell, it will always give you vbDouble