# Are ranges in VBA not accepting Double declared value?

Tags: vba, range, double, declaration

I have the following code where I pick a value from a named range and store it in a variable declared as a Double. Later on, after changing the variable or not I want to reassign it to the named range. But here I get an Overflow error. The error disappears if I change the variable into an Integer. For information, I am working on a Mac.

'''

```
Dim maxDepth As Double
i=0

Do Until Range("scopeID").offset(i, 0) = ""
    maxDepth = Range("currentDepth").offset(i, 0)

    ' some code here that possibly changes the value based on some conditions

    Range("currentDepth").offset(i, 0) = maxDepth
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

'''

Comment: I don't have the time to test this but try the explicit ```Value2``` property rather than the implicit ```Value```. So, replace all three occurrences of ```.offset(i, 0)``` with ```.offset(i, 0).Value2``` and see if that works. Quick read on the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17363466/8488913)

Comment: Not sure anyone can tell without knowing what the rest of your code does.

Comment: I assume you don't have the overflow because of the double but because of `i` overflowing.